# Can you check if two classes are the same using Chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am working on  project using Karma, Mocha, and Chai for unit testing and am running into an issue with matching two classes. Essentially, I have a `Root` class that creates, stores, and manages items of the `Child` class. However, this `Root` class also exposes the `Child` as a static property for standalone use.

#### ./src/Root.js:

```
import Child from './Child';

export class Root {
    constructor() {
        this.children = [];
    }

    addChild() {
        this.children.push(new Child());
    }

    static Child() {
        return Child;
    }
}
```

This part works; from manual testing, it appears that `Root.Child` is equivalent to `Child`. However, I'd like to add a unit test to ensure that this is always the case. And this is where I'm stuck.

#### ./test/root.spec.js:

```
import Root from './src/Root';
import Child from './src/Child';

describe('Root', () => {
    it('should be a class', () => {
        expect(Root).to.be.a('function'); // Passes
    });

    it('should expose Child as a static prop', () => {
        expect(Root).to.have.property('Child'); // Passes by itself
        expect(Root.Child).to.equal(Child); // Fails
    });
});
```

When I run this test, I get a failure stating: `expected [Function: Child] to equal [Function: Child]`

I understand that the `Child` imported in Root is "separate" from the one imported in root.spec, so my question is, using Chai (and I suppose this could extend to JavaScript in general) is there a way to check of the two classes match? Or is there I better way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not invoking the static method in your `Root` class. That means that the test is checking equality between your `Child` class and the function that returns your `Child` class.

```js
class MyClass {}

class MyOtherClass {
  static MyClass() {
    return MyClass
  }
}

console.log(MyClass === MyClass) //true
console.log(MyOtherClass.MyClass === MyClass) //false
console.log(MyOtherClass.MyClass() === MyClass) //true
```

Comment: You're right! That was supposed to be a getter, not a method. I should've known it was a silly mistake... Thanks!